# Error-Handle powershell command in Batch File

Tags: powershell, batch-file, error-handling

I have not been able to figure out how I would be able to get this to work.

I want this to extract zip like it to extract zip, but if it fails [(Picture of error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVfiQ.png) I want it to delete the zip and curl it again.

The reason it would give an error is for corrupt zip, it is if the user closes the program during the initial zip install.

```
if EXIST "%UserProfile%\Downloads\100 Player Among US.zip" (
        echo "---Zip Detected, Extracting it now---"
        powershell -Command "Expand-Archive -Force '%UserProfile%\Downloads\100 Player Among US.zip' '%UserProfile%\Downloads\'"

        if There is an error  (
        DEL "%UserProfile%\Downloads\100 Player Among US.zip"
        echo "---Corrpupted Zip, I'm installing it again---"
        curl "link"
        )
    )
```

Comment: [1] why are you mixing BAT/CMD and powershell stuff? [2] if you need to use BAT stuff, then call something like 7zip instead of powershell.

Comment: I would abandon legacy cmd shell script (batch) and write the script in PowerShell instead.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I cant use 7zip since it is not preinstalled on windows. :/

Comment: @Bill_Stewart ps1 files cant be run on windows by default and introduces more complications for the user.

Comment: PowerShell is now standard on all Windows platforms since Windows 7 and the recommended execution policy is `RemoteSigned`. (Note that execution policy is an administrator safety feature, not a security boundary.)

Comment: @Wolfhound905 - i understand about "not-pre-installed". [*grin*] _however_, i would go with powershell if at all possible. it is far, far simpler to work with if you stay in powershell for the entire process. ///// in any case, i see that you have a working solution. _excellent!_ [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey If you would like to check out how I got it working, here is the link
https://github.com/Wolfhound905/Among-Us-Custom-Server-Launcher/blob/main/Among%20Us%20100%20Players.bat

Comment: @Wolfhound905 - neat! thank you for the link ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to handle the Powershell error in the batch script, you must return a non-zero exit code from Powershell in case of an error.

Powershell returns a non-zero exit code in these cases:

- The script is terminated using the `exit N` statement, where *N* specifies a non-zero exit code.
- A terminating error is not catched, so it "leaves" the script.
- Syntax error in the script, e. g. invalid command.

By default, `Expand-Archive` causes a non-terminating error when extraction fails. We can turn that into a terminating error by passing [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.1) `-ErrorAction Stop` or by setting [preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.1) `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` befor calling the command.

Example using `-ErrorAction` parameter:

```bat
powershell -Command "Expand-Archive -ErrorAction Stop -Force '%UserProfile%\Downloads\100 Player Among US.zip' '%UserProfile%\Downloads\'"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   :: Handle the error
)
```

Example using `$ErrorActionPreference`:

```bat
powershell -Command "$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'; Expand-Archive -Force '%UserProfile%\Downloads\100 Player Among US.zip' '%UserProfile%\Downloads\'"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   :: Handle the error
)
```

Setting the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable can simplify scripts that run multiple commands.

Comment: Thank you! I actually now do hash checking!